# Word: Autofill "Insert Hyperlink" dialog box

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I'm using Word 2010 on Windows 7. When inserting hyperlink (Ctrl+K), I used to be able to switch to my browser (Opera 12) and switch back and get the address field filled with the URL from the browser without any manual copying and pasting. The behavior disappeared with the change of default browser to Opera Chromium. I've changed it back to Opera 12, but the behavior hasn't returned. Indeed, since this is a feature of Word's (rather than Opera's), I should be able to get it to work with whichever browser I want. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The feature came back by itself after reloading Opera (without even reloading Word).